# Como medir tempos em programas multi-thread em C

Tags: c, c++, linux, thread

Estou fazendo  um trabalho com multi thread em c, e preciso calcular o tempo de uma determinada parte do programa, alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu possa fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, o que voce quer fazer tem um nome, se chama **profiling**. De uma lida rapida **[AQUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming))** para entender melhor no que significa essa técnica.

Isso é bastante usado para melhorar codigos que precisam ter alta performance, pouco usado na vida real de programador, mas uma tecnica bastante interessante de conhecer.

Use a ferramenta **[gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/)** para fazer isso.

Boa sorte!